# Does the Android M Doze state have multiple states itself?

Tags: android, adb, alarmmanager, alarm, android-6.0-marshmallow

I slightly modified this app :https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/JobScheduler

It set alarms using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle  and schedules an alarm to go off every 1 minute and log it.

According to Doze documentation, if this app is running while the phone is in Doze mode, only one alarm should be going off per 15 minutes. I'm not seeing that behavior .

On a a nexus 5 running Android M. After starting the app and the whole alarm scheduling process, I put the phone into Doze using the provided abd commands...

adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle -h

...From the log, I have seen around 30 minutes of alarms going off once per minute, then finally they are 15 minutes apart for about an hour. Then back to once per minute, and then back to 15 minutes apart. The phone was completely undisturbed during the test.

Does anyone know why this is? I was under the impression that the phone would immediately be in Doze mode after those adb commands , and that the alarms would be going off 15 minutes apart from the start.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW, I haven't bothered with the commands, as I don't trust 'em. I just let the device go into Doze mode under its own (lack of) power. I am not quite sure where you are getting your every-15-minutes bit from, though, as I cannot find a reference to "15" in [the behavior changes documentation](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for replaying. I didn't explain that part clearly, my mistake. In the quick docs for the setExactAndAllowWhileIdle  method, it is stated : "Under normal system operation, it will not dispatch these alarms more than about every minute (at which point every such pending alarm is dispatched); when in low-power idle modes this duration may be significantly longer, such as 15 minutes"

Comment: From my experience, in actual Doze mode, the gaps between events are much longer, from an hour to a few hours.

Comment: Well the logs for the work ( downloading file ) seemed to be 15 minutes apart. However I see now that there were exceptions in the downloads. Until the 1 min apart logs start up again. I believe this is Idle maintenance mode- the downloads worked here as well. Unfortunately, the gaps between idle maintenance mode were  2- 4 hours long.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, part of my confusion was caused by the adb commands google provided to put the device into doze mode. They are unclear. https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2930&thanks=2930&ts=1439405162  here is how you can actually put it into doze mode.

Comment: See https://newcircle.com/s/post/1739/2015/06/12/diving-into-android-m-doze for more insight into DeviceIdleController, its states, and its commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the relevant adb command docs are incomplete, as you noted in the link to [ISSUE 2930](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2930&thanks=2930&ts=1439405162).

The following command merely prints usage info:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle -h
```

The following command will display the current state including the prerequisites (enabled, not moving, not charging, screen off) for getting into IDLE:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle

  Settings:
    ...
  Whitelist (except idle) system apps:
    ...
  Whitelist (except idle) all app ids:
    ...
  mEnabled=true
  mForceIdle=false
  mSigMotionSensor=null
  mCurDisplay=...
  mScreenOn=false
  mCharging=false
  mSigMotionActive=false
  mState=INACTIVE
```

That shows whether you need to do more setup. E.g. it seems to take 2 or 3 taps on the emulator's power button to get `mScreenOn=false`.

The following command steps towards IDLE mode, but [ISSUE 2930](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2930&thanks=2930&ts=1439405162) explains that you need to step multiple times to get to INACTIVE, IDLE_PENDING, SENSING, then IDLE:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step
```

The following command will force it into idle:

```
adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle
```

BTW the developer docs on [Doze and App Standby](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) were improved recently.

Answer (score 1):

The rate limit for `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` is different when the device is in idle mode. I'm guessing it's taking you 30 minutes for your phone to enter idle mode via Doze, at which point you'll be limited to calling `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` once every 15 minutes.

In Doze mode, your phone will wake up periodically for an Idle Maintenance period of up to 10 minutes. During those 10 minutes it will wake up from idle mode and your rate limit will be adjusted to once every minute. After the maintenance window ends, you're seeing it go back to once every 15 minutes.

The Idle Maintenance windows are described in the docs: http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#understand_doze